# Not retrieving lat/lng values with file_get_contents?

Tags: php, json, google-maps

I've searched extensively for a solution to this problem, but to no avail. I'm trying to retrieve the latitude and longitude values from a given address. However, whether I use file_get_contents or CURL, $lat and $lng values are not returned. I'm receiving no errors in error_log, using PHP 5.2, allow_url_fopen = On in php.ini, and echoing $address returns the proper address from the form. Furthermore, manually inputting that address into the URL works with GeoCode. I've tried no spaces, str_replace, no commas, etc. Still, no matter what, I receive nothing when I echo $lat or $lng.

```
$address = $_POST['address'];

$getJSON = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false";
            $contentJSON = file_get_contents($getJSON);
            $Geocode_array = json_decode($contentJSON, true);

$lat = $Geocode_array['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
$lng = $Geocode_array['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

echo $lat;
echo $lng;
echo $address;
```

Comment: `var_dump($contentJSON); var_dump($Geocode_array);`

Comment: I'm receiving OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, though I'm absolutely not over the 2,500 limit.

Comment: Is your server on a shared IP address?  Have you tried using a key in your request?

Comment: By shared IP, you mean a shared web-hosting service? Then I think so. In terms of a key, the latest version of google's geocode doesn't require one (unfortunately in this case). Only for the Google Maps V3 API is it required, but I don't believe it's even supported as a parameter for GeoCode. So what are my options?

Comment: It must be something with your host. I can call up the geo-coords on one word addresses using the code you've posted above. I'd say wait and try again either later tonight or tomorrow, but I don't know if that will fix any reliability issues on your host's end.